# Are keywords in resolv.conf case sensitive?

Tags: glibc, resolv.conf, case-sensitivity

Looking around I have found out the following about `/etc/resolv.conf` valid formatting:

- Trailing whitespace is allowed
- Leading whitespace is NOT allowed
- DNS records are case insensitive, though you [may have weird issues in applications that lowercase everything](https://serverfault.com/a/752295/313521)

However, I can't find anywhere whether the `resolv.conf` *keywords* are case insensitive or case sensitive.  They seem to be lowercase *usually*, but do they have to be?  Is it an error if I find a server where they are in uppercase?

A google search turns up [this forum thread](https://forum.bigfix.com/t/matching-etc-resolv-conf-with-multiple-nameserver-lines/2090/3), where a code example seems to indicate that the keywords are case **in**sensitive.  However, there is no link to any authoritative documentation.

Are `/etc/resolv.conf` keywords (such as `nameserver`) case sensitive?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They are certainly case sensitive in the glibc resolver libraries.  Note the use of `strncmp` (case sensitive compare) rather than `strncasecmp` (case insensitive compare) in the MATCH function within [glibc res_init.c](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/a2f34833b1042d5d8eeb263b4cf4caaea138c4ad/resolv/res_init.c#L231).

This code is responsible for reading + parsing the `/etc/resolv.conf` file.

```c
#define MATCH(line, name) \
    (!strncmp(line, name, sizeof(name) - 1) && \
    (line[sizeof(name) - 1] == ' ' || \
     line[sizeof(name) - 1] == '\t'))

    if ((fp = fopen(_PATH_RESCONF, "rce")) != NULL) {
        /* No threads use this stream.  */
        __fsetlocking (fp, FSETLOCKING_BYCALLER);
        /* read the config file */
        while (fgets_unlocked(buf, sizeof(buf), fp) != NULL) {
        /* skip comments */
        if (*buf == ';' || *buf == '#')
            continue;
        /* read default domain name */
        if (MATCH(buf, "domain")) {
            if (haveenv)    /* skip if have from environ */
                continue;
            cp = buf + sizeof("domain") - 1;
```

Further, quick example showing how lookup breaks with NAMESERVER rather than nameserver.

```
# cat /etc/resolv.conf
options timeout:2 attempts:5
; generated by /sbin/dhclient-script
search eu-west-1.compute.internal
nameserver 172.31.0.2
# getent hosts www.google.com
2a00:1450:400b:802::2004 www.google.com
# sed -i 's/nameserver/NAMESERVER/' /etc/resolv.conf
# getent hosts www.google.com
#
```

Answer (score 4):

Looking at [the source code for glibc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/download.html), the macro that tries to match strings like `domain` and `nameserver` is—

```c
#define MATCH(line, name) \
  (!strncmp(line, name, sizeof(name) - 1) && \
  (line[sizeof(name) - 1] == ' ' || \
   line[sizeof(name) - 1] == '\t'))
```

and the line that matches the `search` keyword looks like—

```c
if (MATCH(buf, "search")) {
```

`strncmp()` is case-sensitive, so that line will only match a lower-case `search` (followed by either a space or a tab).  The same is true for the other keywords.

The parsing code ignores non-matching lines, so you won't see an error if you accidentally use `SEARCH` instead of `search`: the line will just be ignored.

Comment: Thanks!  I accepted the other answer due to the direct link to the code, and the demonstration, but I particularly appreciate the last line of this answer.